# Unable to make code reusable inside map operator

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to functional programming, I have a block of code for lhs and rhs links. Both of them take same array as an input and split the array and return first and second index of the new Splitted array. I am trying to move the redundant logic into a separate function. Any inputs are appreciated.

```
this.lhsLinks = this.contractTiles$.pipe(map( x => {
  const chunksSize = x.length / 2;
  const temparray = [];

  for (let i = 0, j = x.length; i < j; i += chunksSize) {
    const elementList = x.slice(i, i + chunksSize);
    temparray.push(elementList);
  }

  if (temparray.length > 0) {
    return temparray[1];
  }
}

this.rhsLinks= this.contractTiles$.pipe(map( x => {
  const chunksSize = x.length / 2;
  const temparray = [];

  for (let i = 0, j = x.length; i < j; i += chunksSize) {
    const elementList = x.slice(i, i + chunksSize);
    temparray.push(elementList);
  }

  if (temparray.length > 0) {
    return temparray[0];
  }
}
```